# Struggling with XRDP (Fedora 19 connecting from Windows 7)

Tags: fedora, remote-desktop

I am new to Linux and have a server running Fedora 19 and need to see the desltop from a Windows 7 machine.  I have found a lot of conflicting advice on different methods and have plumped for the xRDP approach following [this install and set up method](http://www.scottalanmiller.com/linux/2013/08/18/installing-xrdp-on-fedora-19/).

However, when I try to connect I get this error: 
[image]

I can log in via SSH using putty and have a command line terminal session but if I try tunneling the SSH connection with TightVNC (following [these directions](http://www.techotopia.com/index.php/Remote_Access_to_the_Fedora_Linux_Desktop)), I get this error:
[image]

I have no direct access to the actual machine and so cannot see the desktop and therefore cannot follow any of the (plentiful) advice about how to set this up using the GUI controls.  The solution will have to be through the command line.  I believe the Fedora box is running Gnome3 and I can get a PID for xRDP, so I know that is running.

My gut feeling is that there is a vital step missing from the "how to" instructions I linked above but I don't know what.

Comment: Since you seem to have RDP running on Fedora, have you tried connecting with 'mstsc' from Windows.

Comment: Yes.  Unfortunately that gives me the first fail screenshot.

Comment: Have you tried it with the firewall disabled?

Comment: No but I tried opening a port (I think it was 3389) as per on of the how-to descriptions

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have a solution to my goal, if not the exact question.  Basically I ditched XRDP altogether as I was getting nowhere.  It promised to be an easy route to remote desktopping to the server but wasn't.  Instead I returned to the VNC via SSH tunnel method and by following [this tutorial](http://www2.cbunney.com/blogs/index.php/2012/07/25/fedora-17-vnc-server-setup?blog=5) I managed to get everything working after opening the required ports in the firewall.